# Keeping only features with certain attribute values in osm2pgsql

Tags: osm2pgsql

Is there a way to use osm2pgsql and have it only keep features that have values for certain attributes?

For example, only keeping features which have a value (i.e. not null) in the default  `highway` column?

I saw in [the manual](https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#the-pgsql-output) that you can use `--hstore-match-only`, but I would like to skip the `hstore` column completely, and simply only import features for which the `highway` column will be non-NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can code, I can really recommend you to use the [osm2pgsql flex output](https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#the-flex-output). In the osm2pgsql repository is an [example](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/e1631b1bf6c5b5e7ac525531758a2d8c63ea3577/flex-config/route-relations.lua) for your highway requirement.

If you just want an easy solution, you can first filter your osm file with [Osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#filtering-by-tags) and then upload it to the postgres database with osm2pgsql:

```
osmium tags-filter rome.osm.pbf w/highway -o highways-in-rome.osm.pbf
```

or

```
osmium tags-filter rome.osm.pbf w/highway=primary -o highways-in-rome.osm.pbf
```

Comment: I forgot about osmium! Thank you, it works perfectly. I don't have any experience with Lua unfortunately, but the osmium solution works great.